# Unable to print to Brother printer by wifi

Tags: wireless, printing, brother

I have 2 computers running Kubuntu 14.04 64 bit and this Brother printer: MFC-J6910DW

The printer has wifi capabilities.  I've set up a fixed IP address: `192.168.1.191.`
The router address is `191.168.1.1`

I've installed the drivers in both computers.
Both of them can do successfully: `192.168.1.1`
I connect specifying these data *manually* in the KDE wizard for adding a new remote printer:

- `lpr://192.168.1.131`
- The queue is `BINARY_P1`
- I specify the right driver, supplied by Brother.

In computer A, I can print successfully, whereas in Computer B, when I try to print something, it appears in the queue as a job, and it says it is completed, but never prints. No error message appears.

Why can I not print in computer B?
How can I diagnose the problem?

[Here is the official page for Brother printers in Linux](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/index.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has worked for me following the tip of technical support of Brother:

> I would recommend removing the printer driver and re-installing using
>   our install utility that will automate the download/install process.
>   You may access this installation utility at the [following
>   location](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc8890dw_all&os=127&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625).

After running the Brother install utility, I was offered these choices:

```
0: ipp14
1: socket
2: https
3: ipp
4: ipps
5: lpd
6: http
7: serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
8: smb
9: hp
10: parallel:/dev/lp0
11: hpfax
12 (I): Specify IP address.
13 (A): Auto. (usb://dev/usblp0)
```

At first, I tried number 12 and didn't work.
So, I created another printer with the URI: `lpr://192.168.1.131` instead of `socket://192.168.1.131` and it works now. :-)

Comment: How is this different than the way you tried in question?

Comment: I've used the install utility from Brother, instead of specifying the data manually.

Comment: You didn't say in your question that you used manual settings. Please clear the question and answer. As I can see, you used same `lpr` prototcol in both.

Comment: I've made more clear both the question and the answer.

Comment: Had a similar issue on Ubunt 20.04 LTS and this fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with Brother HL-L2352DW on Ubuntu 17.10 . 
It started working when I installed it with Brother install utility with LPD uri (lpd://BRW2C6FC9312B2C/BINARY_P1) and after some turning off and on the printer and the router. I've have also set the static IP for the printer on my router.
PS. It started working after some idle time (like 10 minutes) - it printed the installation test page after that time...